# concatenate each array into a string

Tags: php, arrays

So I have next array:

```
    Array ( [1] => Array ( [FIRST_NAME] => John [LAST_NAME] => Bon ) 
            [2] => Array ( [FIRST_NAME] => Ray [LAST_NAME] => Bam ) 
          )
```

How can I get the next result?:

Names: John Bon, Ray Bam

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: @TomUdding If you feel smart you could have just provided something that I could have searched and documented myself in order to achieve what I asked.

Comment: You should search for something before asking about it on Stack Overflow. This might help you; foreach loop, implode, concatenate.

Comment: @TomUdding You see? Now you're being useful . Thank you.

Comment: You are supposed to make at least a little effort for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`foreach()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop. The code below gives you the index of the inner array (`0, 1, 2, 3, etc.`) and the inner array itself. Then you can use the keys of the inner arrays to display the the values from that key.

```
$array = array(
    array("FIRST_NAME" => "Jon", "LAST_NAME" => "Doe"),
    array("FIRST_NAME" => "Jane", "LAST_NAME" => "Doe"),
    array("FIRST_NAME" => "Johnny", "LAST_NAME" => "Doe"),
    array("FIRST_NAME" => "Janie", "LAST_NAME" => "Doe"));

$output = "";

foreach ($array as $i => $values) { // get the inner arrays from the outer array
    if ($i != 0) { // check if it is not the first array
        $output .= ", {$values['FIRST_NAME']} {$values['LAST_NAME']}";
    } else {
        $output .= "{$values['FIRST_NAME']} {$values['LAST_NAME']}";
    }
}

echo $output;
// Jon Doe, Jane Doe, Johnny Doe, Janie Doe
```

In this code the values (e.g. `{$values['FIRST_NAME']}`)from the inner arrays are interpolated in the string, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4676804/5914775) for more information on why you should do it like this.

See https://3v4l.org/K5s82 for the output.