# Printing an array in a different format

Tags: php, mysql

I have extracted some data from mysql database using php. In the script, i have

```
$result=mysql_query("select mac,ip_add from arp_table where ip_add='$var'");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);
```

The result comes out as

```
Array ( [0] => 08 CC 68 71 A1 C0 [1] => 1.10.0.0.98 )
```

But i would want to modify it and have it come out as

`MAC Address for 1.10.0.0.98 is 08 CC 68 71 A1 C0`
How can i achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
print_r($row);
```

with

```
echo "MAC Address for {$row[1]} is {$row[0]}"
```

Please, also note that using variables inside strings only works with double quotes strings. The curly braces are only needed for particular variable names, or when you want to use array accessors.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311368/which-is-better-on-performance-double-quoted-strings-with-variables-or-single-q) for more information about concatenation and single vs double quoted strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 'MAC Address for ' + ip_add + ' is ' + mac
from arp_table 
where ip_add='$var'
```

Answer (score 1):

just do it with

```
if(!empty($row)) {

   echo "MAC Address for ".$row[1]." is ".$row[0];

}
```

hope this will sure help you

Answer (score 1):

```
function printArpRow($row) {
        echo "MAC Address for {$row[0]} is {$row[0]}";
    }
```

Then change print_r($row) by printArpRow($row)

Answer (score 1):

Using your actual code, change `print_r($row);` for:

```
echo "MAC Address for ".$row[0]." is ".$row[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result=mysql_query("select concat('MAC Address for',mac,'is',ip_add) as str from arp_table where ip_add='$var'");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);
```